# Cómo mostrar imagenes en una plantilla de correo

Tags: php, html, email

```html
include('sendemail.php');
  //Mando a llamar la funcion que se encarga de enviar el correo electronico
/* Configuracion de variables para enviar el correo */
$mail_username="gp727rdx@gmail.com";//Correo electronico saliente ejemplo: tucorreo@gmail.com
$mail_userpassword="123456AsdfG";//Tu contraseña de gmail
$mail_addAddress= $email1;//correo electronico que recibira el mensaje (apparmas@gmail.com)
$template="mail/email_template.html";//Ruta de la plantilla HTML para enviar nuestro mensaje

/*Inicio captura de datos enviados por $_POST para enviar el correo */
$mail_setFromEmail=$mail_addAddress;
$mail_setFromName=$_SESSION['dondequeda_nombre'].' '.$_SESSION['dondequeda_apellido'];
      //http://localhost/fegir/apparmas_fegir/informe3.php?codigo=".$x1 Cambiar para enviar el asunto del mensaje
$txt_message="Hay una novedad con el arma".$nserie_email;
$mail_subject="Alerta! Novedad en arma:".$_POST['nserie'];

sendemail($mail_username,$mail_userpassword,$mail_setFromEmail,$mail_setFromName,
      $mail_addAddress,$txt_message,$mail_subject,$template);//Enviar el mensaje
      
      
//archivo sendmail.php

function sendemail($mail_username,$mail_userpassword,$mail_setFromEmail,$mail_setFromName,$mail_addAddress,$txt_message,$mail_subject, $template){
 require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
 $mail = new PHPMailer;
 $mail->isSMTP();                            // Establecer el correo electrónico para utilizar SMTP
 $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';             // Especificar el servidor de correo a utilizar
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                     // Habilitar la autenticacion con SMTP
 $mail->Username = $mail_username;          // Correo electronico saliente ejemplo: tucorreo@gmail.com
 $mail->Password = $mail_userpassword;   // Tu contraseña de gmail
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                  // Habilitar encriptacion, `ssl` es aceptada
 $mail->Port = 25;                          // Puerto TCP  para conectarse 
 $mail->setFrom($mail_setFromEmail, $mail_setFromName);//Introduzca la dirección de la que debe aparecer el correo electrónico. Puede utilizar cualquier dirección que el servidor SMTP acepte como válida. El segundo parámetro opcional para esta función es el nombre que se mostrará como el remitente en lugar de la dirección de correo electrónico en sí.
 $mail->addReplyTo($mail_setFromEmail, $mail_setFromName);//Introduzca la dirección de la que debe responder. El segundo parámetro opcional para esta función es el nombre que se mostrará para responder
 $mail->addAddress($mail_addAddress);   // Agregar quien recibe el e-mail enviado
 $message = file_get_contents($template);
 $message = str_replace('{{first_name}}', $mail_setFromName, $message);
 $message = str_replace('{{message}}', $txt_message, $message);
 $message = str_replace('{{customer_email}}', $mail_setFromEmail, $message);
 $mail->isHTML(true);  // Establecer el formato de correo electrónico en HTML

 $mail->Subject = $mail_subject;
 $mail->msgHTML($message);
 if(!$mail->send()) {
  echo '<p style="color:red">No se pudo enviar el mensaje..';
  echo 'Error de correo: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo."</p>";
 } else {

 }
 //   echo '<p style="color:green">Tu mensaje ha sido enviado!</p>';
}


//plantilla del correo


  <!--Estilo de Plantilla-->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
    body {
        font-family: "Roboto";
    }
    p{
      font-family: 'Saira Extra Condensed', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol', 'Noto Color Emoji';
      font-weight: 700;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: #fff;
    }
</style>
<br><br>
<table style="max-width: 900px; padding: 10px; margin:0 auto; border-collapse: collapse;">
 <tr>
  <td style="background-color: #222; text-align: left; padding: 0">
            <center><img width="20%" style="display:block; margin: 1.5% 3%" src="logo.png"></center>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr style="background-image: url(img/fondo_correo.png); background-size: 100% 100%; background-attachment: fixed">
        <td>
            <div style="color: #34495e; margin: 4% 10% 2%; text-align: justify;font-family: sans-serif">
                <img width="9%" style="display:block; float: left; position: static;" src="img/alerta.png"><br><p style="margin: 2px; font-size: 20px; color: #B32020; ">Alerta de Novedad de Arma</p><br><br>
                <p style="color: #000; margin: 0 0 7px; color:#fff;">Cordial Saludo,</p>
                <p style="color: #000; margin: 0 0 7px; color:#FCFEFF;">Sebastian Rojas</p>
    <p style="margin: 2px; font-size: 15px;"></p>|
                <p style="margin: 2px; font-size: 15px">Esta es una notificación de que el arma con número de serie #XD403, se encuentra en mal estado y necesita inmediatamente que se realice la debida inspección.</p>
                <p style="margin: 2px; font-size: 15px">Para continuar con el proceso pulsa el siguiente botón, el cual te redirigirá al sistema automaticamente.</p>
            </div>
            <br>
        <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center">
            <a style="text-decoration: none; padding: 10px; font-weight: 300; font-size: 16px; color: #ffffff; background-color: #1883ba; border-radius: 6px; border: 1px solid #1883ba;" href="http://fegir.org/scow/">IR A SCOW</a> 
            <br><br><br>        
                <tr>
               <td style="background-color: #222; text-align: left; padding: 10">
                        <center><p style="margin: 2px; font-size: 15px; color:#fff;">¡Si tienes alguna duda, solo contáctanos!</p></center>
                        <b><center><p style="margin: 2px; font-size: 15px; color:#fff;">Contáctanos:</p></center></b>
                        <center><p style="margin: 2px; font-size: 15px; color:#fff;"><b>Teléfono:</b> 310 322 88 93</p><p style="margin: 2px; font-size: 15px; color:#fff;"><b>Correo Electrónico:</b> contacto@sofu.com</p></center>
               </td>
             </tr>
        </div>
 </tr>
</table>
```

tengo una plantilla para correos, lo que sucede es que cuando se envía, el contenido se ve, es decir, la letra, pero no las imagenes, apesar de que las llamo correctamente desde la carpeta en donde se contienen, alguna idea?, cabe decir que estoy usando la función de php para enviar correos.

Comment: Como no pongas el código que usas para generar el email poco te podremos ayudar. Pásate por el [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) y revisa las secciones de [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Después [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/240152/edit) tu pregunta y añade cuanta información puedas.

Comment: Ahí agregué el código, gracias por el apunte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todas las imágenes que usas tienen rutas relativas, por lo tanto el gestor de correo no las puede localizar.

Para que funcionen se me ocurren tres métodos:

## 1.- Usar rutas absolutas.

Lo malo de este método es que los gestores de correo las pueden bloquear y lo bueno es que no añade peso adicional al correo.

```html
 <img src="https://placekitten.com/50/50">
```

---

## 2.- Incrustar la imagen en el html, codificada en base64.

Pese a añadir el peso total de la imagen al correo (como si de un adjunto ordinario se tratase), facilita la visualización porque el gestor de correo no la bloqueará ni pedirá permiso al usuario para mostrarla.

```html
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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 -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 1. Elemento de listajgV00AA7CiihDGXIBQ5Fc7qCLz8o/KiimxGI6L5n3R+VSRjmiigC+AMCiiimI/9k=">
```

Puedes encontrar [un montón de sitios](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=base64+online+image+encode) para codificar las imágenes, como por ejemplo https://www.base64-image.de/

---

## 3.- Incrustar las imágenes en la cabecera del correo.

Con las mismas características que incrustarlas en el HTML pero usando las funciones de la librería de correo.

`PHPMailer::addEmbeddedImage($path, $cid, $name)`

- **$path:** ruta y nombre local del fichero a adjuntar (obligatorio).
- **$cid:** identificador del la imagen; para referenciarla posteriormente (obligatorio).
- **$name:** nombre de la imagen adjunta (opcional).

Por ejemplo: `$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('logo.png','milogo','logo.png')`

para luego usarla en el HTML del cuerpo del correo:

`<img width="20%" style="display:block; margin: 1.5% 3%" src="cid:milogo">`

[Ejemplos](https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/phpmailer/AddEmbeddedImage/php-phpmailer-addembeddedimage-method-examples.html)

> **NOTA**
>
> Por lo que he visto, al redactar esta respuesta, el método
>   `AddEmbeddedImage` ha debido sufrir modificaciones según la versión
>   usada, verifica los parámetros válidos en la versión que utilices.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo por la ayuda, ya pude resolverlo...

Answer (score 0):

Estoy teniendo el mismo problema que Rafael. Quiero insertar una imagen en un email. Estoy probando de dos maneras distintas. De momento estoy probando localmente, osea, desde mi servidor local me mando emails.
La primera es usando el método `addEmbeddedImage` donde el primer parámetro es la ruta y el segundo el ID donde se debería poner la imagen:

```
 $mail->addEmbeddedImage($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/directorio/photos/carlos/48/1.jpg", "prueba");
```

La segunda forma es convirtiendo a base64:

```
$urlImagen = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/directorio/photos/carlos/48/1.jpg"));
$urlImagen = "data:image/jpeg;base64.$urlImagen";
```

Pero no consigo hacerlo de ninguna manera. ¿Que puedo estar haciendo mal?