# No se visualiza logo en el correo

Tags: php, wordpress

Estuve intentando muchas veces y logre que en la vista preliminar se visualice,
pero al enviar un correo no se ve. Qué puede ser?

```
<?php

do_action( 'bp_before_email_header' );

echo '<img src= "/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/CLARO-300x102.png"  width="170" height="115">';

do_action( 'bp_after_email_header' );
?>
```

Gracias!!!

Comment: pon la ruta completa a la imagen, no relativa. Por ejemplo: `<img src= "http://www.midominio.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/CLARO-300x102.png"....`

Comment: Gracias!!! Era super sencillo

Comment: hey @Fly coloca ese comentario a modo de respuesta y Jennifer, acepta esa respuesta para mantener la buena salud del sitio, gracias :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes poner la ruta completa de la imagen, no relativa, porque el gestor de correo del destinatario no sabrá donde encontrarla.

Por ejemplo:

`<img src= "http://www.midominio.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/CLARO-300x102.png"....`

Revisa esta respuesta: [Cómo mostrar imagenes en una plantilla de correo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/240152/c%c3%b3mo-mostrar-imagenes-en-una-plantilla-de-correo/240375#240375)