# ¿No muestra imágenes enviadas por medio de PHPMailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer

Tengo estas configuraciones en mi PHPMailer:

```
        //Nueva instancia PHPMailer.
        $mail = new PHPMailer;

        //SMTP debugging
        // 0 = off (usar en producción)
        // 1 = mensaje cliente
        // 2 = cliente y servidor mensaje
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

        //Usar SMTP     
        $mail->isSMTP();
        //$mail->isSMTP(true);

        //Servidor GMAIL: Host = smtp.gmail.com, Port 587, SMTPSecure tls
        $mail->Host = 'servidor.net';
        // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        //Puerto gmail
        $mail->Port = 465;
        //Encryption system SSL = ssl (deprecated) or TLS = tls
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        //Autoridad
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        //Usuario GMAIL
        $mail->Username = "example@example.com";
        //Contraseña GMAIL
        $mail->Password = "123456";

        //Caracteres utf-8.
        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        //Desde
        $mail->From = "example@example.com";//no-reply@example.com
        $mail->FromName = "example.com";
        //Enviar a:
        $mail->addAddress($email, $first_name);
        //Subject
        $mail->Subject = 'Title';

        //Usar HTML
        $mail->isHTML(true);

        $mail->AddEmbeddedImage('https://example.com/assets/img/website/logo/logo1.png', 'logo1');
        //$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('assets/img/website/logo/logo1.png', 'logo1');
        //$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('../assets/img/website/logo/logo1.png', 'logo1');

        $mail->Body = '
          //Intentos 1
          <img src="example.com/assets/img/website/logo/logo1.png" width="100">
          <!--<img src="../assets/img/website/logo/logo1.png" width="100">-->
          //Intentos 2
          <img src="cid:logo1" width="100">
          //Intentos 3
          <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" width="100">
        ';

        /*$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
            'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
            )
        );*/

        //Enviar
        $mail->send();
```

He observado varios artículos, documentación oficial pero no logró que se muestren las imágenes en los correos enviados.

Incluso he seguido este articulo aquí en StackOverflow [Cómo mostrar imagenes en una plantilla de correo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/240152/c%C3%B3mo-mostrar-imagenes-en-una-plantilla-de-correo)

Hace falta alguna configuración adicional en PHPMailer.

---

Otro de los errores a dados a todos los intentos es que las imágenes que se insertan se suben como adjunto, con opción a descargar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo el punto de mandar las imágenes en base64, en todo caso la solución sería buscar por qué los motores de correo electrónico como gmail, hotmail, etc, bloquean tus imágenes con base 64. Te sugiero poner rutas absolutas, de otra manera los motores te detectan como spam/virus.

Comment: @FernandoUrban Ya lo he intentado de todas las formas, el punto de manar las imágenes en `base64` es por el articulo de StackOverflow https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/240152/c%C3%B3mo-mostrar-imagenes-en-una-plantilla-de-correo donde muestra dicho ejemplo y, dado a que realmente quiero solucionar el problema realizo todas las pruebas con distintos ejemplos, pero bueno nada de resultado.

Comment: Creo que te podría estar retornando errores debido a que el base 64 es demasiado largo en el intento 3. En el intento 2 no sé qué tratas de renderizar ahí dentro y en el Intento 1 si mandas esa ruta relativa jamás el cliente de correo va a saber qué cargar. ¿Por qué no ocupas rutas absolutas?

Comment: que no muestre las imagenes. apuesto a que estas viendo los correos por outlook, si es asi debes permitir la descarga de imagenes

Comment: @JackNavaRow No amigo, realmente outlook, hotmail no me agrada estoy haciendo pruebas con Gmail, pero nada y los correos me llegan directo a la bandeja de entrada, claro que más adelante tengo que hacer pruebas con outlook, hotmail

Comment: @FernandoUrban Ya he intentado con rutas absolutas y con dominio completo y, nada :(

Comment: @Pepe verifica que en el inicio del correo no te tiene bloqueado las imagenes eso generalmente lo hacen para evitar el [XSS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Comment: @JackNavaRow Inspeccionando los elementos obtengo diferentes tipos de llegada a dado a las diferentes pruebas:

Con `src="cid:logo1"` obtengo lo siguiente:

    `<img border="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" width="100" alt="Logo" class="m_3035686689026025387logo">` con rutas absolutas: `<img src="https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/8GRQLapQZSH8uvufdJ9chXM27wkTbbqmLqkxfNetSTsuNnNMUkDM7qvR6DSSd1zQndH-QjBnDQE7DGk=s0-d-e1-ft#http://../assets/img/website/success.svg" alt="my photo" class="CToWUd">`

Comment: @JackNavaRow al igual que con dominio completo `<img src="https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/8GRQLapQZSH8uvufdJ9chXM27wkTbbqmLqkxfNetSTsuNnNMUkDM7qvR6DSSd1zQndH-QjBnDQE7DGk=s0-d-e1-ft#http://example.com/assets/img/website/success.svg" alt="my photo" class="CToWUd">`

Comment: Prueba con la función de esta web: https://www.phpsnaps.com/snaps/view/embed-image-in-email-with-phpmailer lo que hace es usar el html normal y reemplazar luego las imágenes. En realidad hace lo mismo que tu, pero en todas las webs que he consultado, llego a la misma conclusión, debería funcionar tal como lo haces. Excepto por la URL de la imagen, que debería ser un path local.

Comment: @Pepe intente acceder a la imagen y me arroja 404, que tal si colocas la ruta de la imagen en el navegador modo incognito

Comment: @JackNavaRow Pero seguro debe existir alguna solución, porque dado en `outlook` obtienes la opción de desbloquear contenidos, en gmail no aperece ningún mensaje de advertencia, incluso los correos que si son `spam` me llegan correos con imágenes.

Comment: @JackNavaRow Ya probé con ello, pero lo que hace es adjuntar la imagen como archivo y, yo no quiero eso, yo quiero mostrar imágenes de manera normal, como el logotipo, algún diseño elegante en imagen en el cuerpo del correo, no adjuntar imágenes como archivos descabalgarles.

Comment: @JackNavaRow Te sale error, porque cambie la dirección del dominio por example.com, la ruta es correcta, yo accedo normal a la imagen pero con la intervención del dominio de google `https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/8GRQLapQZSH8uvufdJ9chXM27wkTbbqmLqkxfNetSTsuNnNMUkDM7qvR6DSSd1zQndH-QjBnDQE7DGk=s0-d-e1-ft#http://example.com/` también me sale error y, no carga la imagen.

Comment: @JackNavaRow Esta opción `$this->AddEmbeddedImage('/path/to/image.jpg', 'my-image', 'attachment', 'base64', 'image/jpeg');` también la he probado y, al igual que con `src="cid:logo1"` obtengo lo siguiente: `<img border="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" width="100" alt="Logo" class="m_3035686689026025387logo">` no agrega nada en el `src` de `img`

Comment: Prueba a realizar un correo con solo la funcionalidad CID, y usa una ruta relativa para la imagen, como la segunda línea comentada de tu código, puede que al mezclar las tres posibilidades, los clientes de correo detecten algo raro y bloqueen en general.

Comment: @track3r Amigo no es que haya probado todas en una sola, solo las he agregado aquí en el foro de ejemplo, de los intentos realizado :(

Comment: Prueba a crearte una dirección temporal por ejemplo en https://temp-mail.org/ y envía el correo allí, yo lo he probado y funciona. Creo que el problema es en la parte del cliente, no sé que correo usas, pero ahí estará el problema.

Comment: y el `https://` dentro de la imagen del body? tu solo lo indicas asi: `example.com/assets/img/website/logo/logo1.png` y de esta forma no va a tomar la imagen sin el `http`

Comment: @Pepe Cuando la imagen se agrega cómo adjunto es porque en el correo envías la imagen cómo resultado de poner una ruta relativa, al usar una ruta relativa envías una imagen de tu servidor por correo, al usar una ruta absoluta cómo `https://tudominio.com/assets/img.png` no se adjunta la imagen simplemente se lee y así puedes enviar un correo con una imagen sin adjuntarla

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Revisando los comentarios y, los intentos expuestos, donde menciona que si ha logrado insertar una imagen pero que esta se inserta como un archivo adjunto mostrando un botón de descarga.

La razón por la que esta sucede es que Google trata las imágenes más grandes como un archivo adjunto y les permite ver como una imagen de Google Drive. Entendiendo que esto es molesto porque un usuario puede descargar una imagen accidentalmente concuerdo con ello, ya a que nadie le gustaría que esto sucediera más aún con los receptores.

Una solución para evitar que aparezca el botón de descarga es agregar un enlace en la etiqueta imagen -> `a -> img`

```
<a href="#">
    <img src="https://example.com/url-imagen.png" class="logo">
</a>
<!-- Agregar un div, para evitar posible empaqueta-miento de dicha funcionalidad que aparece debajo de la imagen img-->
<div></div>
```

Por otra parte el uso correcto de la funcionalidad `AddEmbeddedImage` de `PHPMiler` funciona correctamente, pude realizar pruebas usando un subdominio donde la librería y el archivo que envía el correo + la imagen en el directorio `root` del subdominio.

Dado aquello debe agregar la siguiente línea:

```
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('email-info.png', 'emailimg', 'attachment', 'base64', 'image/png');
```

Y usarla de la siguiente manera:

```
$mail->Body = '<img src="cid:emailimg" class="img-logo" />';
```

Dado a esta forma no aparece el botón de descarga, pero al dar clic en la imagen esta se abre en un modal de google drive.

Posible solución es utilizar utilizar `headers` personalizados los mismo que se utilizan en la función `mail` de `PHP`:

```
$mail->addCustomHeader('Mime-Version','1.0');
$mail->addCustomHeader('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
```

Algunas referencia importantes

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903967/gmails-new-image-caching-is-breaking-image-links-in-newsletter
- [Headers personalizados](https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_addCustomHeader)
- [Lista de funcionalidades de PHPMailer](https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html)

Comment: Gracias por responder voy a revisarlo :)

Answer (score 3):

Por lo visto el motivo es que no estas direccionando bien la imagen por falta el `http` de la direccion web de la imagen. Yo quiero enviar esta imagen por mail y esta en esta direccion:

> https://townsquare.media/site/366/files/2015/03/Jimi-Hendrix-Eddie-Van-Halen-Tony-Iommi-Dimebag-Darrell.jpg

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces lo ingreso del codigo

**ACTUALIZADO CON PHPMailer**

```
<?php
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

// Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
/* /Server settings
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
$mail->Host       = 'smtp1.example.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username   = 'user@example.com';                     // SMTP username
$mail->Password   = 'secret';                               // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` also accepted
$mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
*/
//Recipients
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('sebastian.dcnx@gmail.com', 'Sebastian');     // Add a recipient
//$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

/* / Attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
*/
// Content
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = '<img src="https://townsquare.media/site/366/files/2015/03/Jimi-Hendrix-Eddie-Van-Halen-Tony-Iommi-Dimebag-Darrell.jpg">';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

$mail->send();
echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}

?>
```

Si notas que en la etiqueta `img` esta la direccion completa de la imagen

`<img src="https://townsquare.media/site/366/files/2015/03/Jimi-Hendrix-Eddie-Van-Halen-Tony-Iommi-Dimebag-Darrell.jpg">`

Este es el mail recien recibido

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fijate de tener bien escrita la direccion de la imagen y puede hacer la prueba copiando la url en el explorador y si no ves la imagen es por la url no esta bien escrita o no hay imagen en ella.

Saludos

Comment: Amigo, como lo dije en los comentarios, si logro insertar una imagen esta se muestra como adjunto, es decir aparece un botón para descargar, lo he puesto en mi pregunta editada.

Comment: Haber si entiendo, lo que tu quieres es enviar un email con una imagen en el `body` y que esta se vea cuando la persona reciba el correo? disculpa, pero no logro entenderte.

Comment: un correo normal amigo, yo tengo ya un diseño responsive con estilos y, todo bien bonito pero al momento de querer poner imágenes como el logotipo y, esa imagen que adjunte en mi pregunta que representa la suscripción correcta a mi sistema pero dicha imagen aparece como un archivo adjunto es decir aparece un botón para descargar esa imagen y, eso no es lo ideal, esto hace que el usuario descargue por error la imagen.

Comment: Esperame que hago la prueba desde PHPMailer

Comment: Ahi esta actualizado y el mail me llega bien a mi correo de Gmail, se puede ver en la imagen que esta actualizada a las 21:29 hora Argentina. No se porque no te llega. Pueden pasarme tu correo?

Comment: Si pasas el mouse (puntero) sobre la imagen en la parte inferior de lado derecho te va aparecer un botón de descarga y, si das clic en la imagen se abre en un modal, he copiado todo tú código y, he enviado la misma imagen a mi correo y, eso me aparece

Comment: Si, a mi me aparece igual.

Answer (score 1):

Todo depende del orígen y la codificación de la imagen:

El método `addEmbeddedImage` sólo acepta archivos locales, por eso no funciona mandando una URL.
Si el orígen es externo deberás obtener primero el contenido y después agregar la imagen con:

```
$mail->addStringEmbeddedImage(file_get_contents('http://dominio.tld/ruta/imagen.png'),'logo');
```

Si el orígen es el sistema de archivos local usa:
`$mail->addEmbeddedImage('ruta/','logo');` cuidando si la ruta es relativa o absoluta.

Si el orígen es una cadena -obtenida desde una base de datos por ejemplo- no deberá ser base64,
ya que la librería hace la codificación, si ya es base64 deberás decodificarla primero:

```
$mail->addStringEmbeddedImage(base64_decode('iVBORw0KG<el resto de la cadena>VrxUpDAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='),'logo');
```

En todos los casos deberás utilizar el cid en el body: `<img src="cid:logo">`
ya que por default enlaces externos y data:image/png;base64 son bloqueados por seguridad.

Answer (score -1):

Prueba a cambiar el **limite de envío de archivos** en el servidor PHP, por defecto está a 2MB, en el archivo php.ini

Prueba aqui [Input type File excede bytes en PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/142367/input-type-file-excede-bytes-en-php/142377#142377)

Espero te sirva